# Jumping algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have made a kind of gravity in a 2D Java game and I am attempting to create a jumping algorithm. I have had a look around and cannot seen to find any help for an algorithm which moves up and down in a wave.

Here is the code in Game.java:

```
package game;

import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends GameLoop{

    public void init(){
        setSize(864,480);
        Thread th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        offscreen = createImage(864,480);
        d = offscreen.getGraphics();
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        d.clearRect(0, 0, 864, 480);
        d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
        d.drawImage(person, x, y, this);
        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }
}
```

And here is the code in GameLoop.java:

```
package game;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.*;

public class GameLoop extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener{

    public int x, y;
    public Image offscreen;
    public Graphics d;
    public boolean up, down, left, right;
    public BufferedImage background, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8, person, s1, s2;
    public int counter, counter2;

    public void run(){
        x = 100;
        y = 100;
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("background.png"));
            w1 = ImageIO.read(new File("walk1.png"));
            w2 = ImageIO.read(new File("walk2.png"));
            w3 = ImageIO.read(new File("walk3.png"));
            w4 = ImageIO.read(new File("walk4.png"));
            w5 = ImageIO.read(new File("walk5.png"));
            w6 = ImageIO.read(new File("walk6.png"));
            w7 = ImageIO.read(new File("walk7.png"));
            w8 = ImageIO.read(new File("walk8.png"));
            s1 = ImageIO.read(new File("stancel.png"));
            s2 = ImageIO.read(new File("stancer.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        person = s1;
        while(true){
            x = 100;
            y = 100;
            while(true){
                if (y <= 304 && up != true){
                    y+=10;
                }
                counter++;
                counter2++;
                if (counter >= 20){
                    counter = 0;
                }
                if (counter >= 0 && counter <= 5 && right == true){
                    person = w1;
                }
                if (counter > 5 && counter < 10 && right == true){
                    person = w2;
                }
                if (counter >= 10 && counter <= 15 && right == true){
                    person = w3;
                }
                if (counter > 15 && right == true){
                    person = w4;
                }
                if (counter2 >= 20){
                    counter2 = 0;
                }
                if (counter2 >= 0 && counter2 <= 5 && left == true){
                    person = w5;
                }
                if (counter2 > 5 && counter2 < 10 && left == true){
                    person = w6;
                }
                if (counter2 >= 10 && counter2 <= 15 && left == true){
                    person = w7;
                }
                if (counter2 > 15 && left == true){
                    person = w8;
                }
                if (left == true){
                    x-=4;
                }
                if (right == true){
                    x+=4;
                }
                if (up == true){
                    y-=4;
                }
                if (down == true){
                    y+=4;
                }
                if ( x <= -10 ){
                    x = -10;
                }
                if ( y <= 0 ){
                    y = 0;
                }
                if ( x >= 824 ){
                    x = 824;
                }
                if ( y >= 304 ){
                    y = 304;
                }
                repaint();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
            left = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
            up = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
            right = true;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
            down = true;
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 37){
            left = false;
            person = s2;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 38){
            up = false;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 39){
            right = false;
            person = s1;
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == 40){
            down = false;
        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

I think I need a counter , `counter3` as a double, but I am not sure of an algorithm that will go up to a certain point on the y axis, then move down. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Game development site would a better place to post this :) http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: *"..help for an algorithm that moves up and down in a wave."*  I think this is more a ballistic trajectory.  The height (`y`) will be given by `s = ut + .5at^2`  where `s` is height, `u` is initial vertical velocity, `t` is time and `a` is gravity.  The horizontal travel will not be affected by gravity (until the object lands, ignoring air resistance), so that formula reduces to `s = ut` where `u` in this case is the horizontal velocity.  It is physics, more than programming per se.

Comment: @bonCodigo  Good point, would vote to close as 'off-topic' if only the 'close' window allowed us to enter an option other than the 4-5 which are wrong for this post.  Angus, it would be better if you deleted this question and asked it on gamedev as suggested.

Comment: Algorithmic questions belong on Stack Overflow as much as anywhere else.  Is the a cross-posting / meta function?

Comment: The question mentions "a kind of gravity". The behavior should be modeled according to the rules of physics in the game world. The easiest set of rules would be Newtonian physics without significant air resistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the simplest wave functions is our old friend `sine`:

[image]

So for a jump motion, you would probably like the first half of a `sine` period.  You could use `java.util.Math`, passing a sequence of numbers from `0` to `180` (how many depends on the number of frames you want the jump to last).  *e.g.*:

```
Math.sin(0.0);   // = 0.0 
Math.sin(30.0);  // = 0.5
Math.sin(60.0);  // = 0.9
Math.sin(90.0);  // = 1.0
Math.sin(120.0); // = 0.9
Math.sin(150.0); // = 0.5
Math.sin(180.0); // = 0.0
```

Comment: This is perfect, I thought about sine, but I wasn't sure how high I would need to go.

Comment: `y = ((int) Math.sin(jumpcount) * 10000);` I have this alg, with a counter that goes from 180 to 360 and looping, but it still won't get a proper jump, it goes straight to the top then goes down using `y+=10;` I think this will oply be a problem with negative numbers, I will try a way around it.

Comment: Have you tried `0` to `180` instead?  Looking at the graph above, you can see that `sin(180.0)` and `sin(360.0)` are zero/ground, while the others in the `180-360` range are negative, while the exact opposite is true for the `0-180` range.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure by what you mean by "moves up and down in a wave".

But anyway, in real world physics, the altitude of an object in free-fall (ignoring air resistance) follows a parabola; i.e. it obeys a formula like:

```
altitude =  maxAltitude - (acceleration * (t - timeOfMaxAltitude))^2
```

(There are other ways of formulating the laws of motion, but this approach is probably what you need for a simple game.)

---

A 1/2 sine wave looks rather like a truncated parabola, and *could* be used instead in a game.  However, you need to realize that it is not an accurate simulation of real-world physics, especially for high jumps.

Comment: @AngusMoore - I guess so.  It entirely depends how your game models / tracks the movement of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to represent the vertical velocity. When you jump, set the vertical velocity to a negative value. On each frame, add the vertical velocity to the vertical position, and add a constant to the velocity to simulate gravity. When there is something underneath, set the velocity back to 0. Experiment with the constant values to get an appropriate jump height.